# rule to rewrite url 123.mysite.com? to mysite.com? in web.config

Tags: url-rewriting

I have a web application which uses SignalR for communication between Users belonging to different groups. Since SignalR imposes a restriction on the number of multiple tabs that can be opened at the same time, I was trying to send different URLs everytime a new tab is opened and redirect to the actual URL using the URL rewrite rule. For eg:- User enters http://guid.localhost:XXX, it should redirect to http://localhost:xxx. Does this require the URL Rewrite extension to be installed on IIS? 
Can anyone please guide on the rule to be added in Web.config to achieve this? Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, install the [URL Rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) extensions. The rule is quite simple:

```
<rule name="My Rule" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="guid.localhost:(.*)" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://localhost:{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

You can define your application rewrite rules in web.config as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
          <rules>
            <!-- YOUR RULES HERE -->
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I installed the URL Rewrite extensions and also added the rule in my web.config. But it didn't work.Below is the rule i added
<rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="redirectRule" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="guid.localhost:(.*)" />
        <action type="Redirect" url="http://localhost:{R:1}" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>